# how do you change the color of the cell in kable output table in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, conditional-formatting, kable

I need to color the cell if the value of the cell is greater than 80. For example, given this data frame called df:

```
dput(df)

structure(list(Server = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Server1", 
"Server2"), class = "factor"), CPU = c(79.17, 93), UsedMemPercent = c(16.66, 
18.95)), .Names = c("Server", "CPU", "UsedMemPercent"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

df[2,2] should be in red color. I was able to change the color of the text by something like this using xtable:

```
df[, 2] = ifelse(df[, 2] > 80, paste("\\color{red}{", round(df[, 2], 2), "}"), round(df[, 2], 2))
```

If I do this and print out the table with kable, it wont print out. Any ideas how can I color the cell in kable output table?

Answer (score 13):

In fact, you don't even need `DT` or `kableExtra` if all you need is the color of that cell. However, as the author of `kableExtra`, I do recommend that package though :P

```
# What u have now
df <-structure(list(Server =structure(1:2, .Label =c("Server1","Server2"), class = "factor"), CPU =c(79.17, 93), UsedMemPercent =c(16.66,18.95)), .Names =c("Server", "CPU", "UsedMemPercent"), row.names =c(NA,-2L), class = "data.frame")
df[, 2] =ifelse(df[, 2]>80,paste("\\color{red}{",round(df[, 2], 2), "}"),round(df[, 2], 2))
# What you need
kable(df, "latex", escape = F)
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, but because the original question was complex so is the answer. Can you provide a general answer as well perhaps using `iris[1:5, ] %>% kable %>% kable_styling(fixed_thead = T)` - it would be super helpful

Comment: Using the example above, if `kable(df, "latex", escape = F) %>% kable_styling(fixed_thead = T)`, I see nothing in `Rmd`, but if i move the cursor over where I expected to see something it kinda gets stuck as though it recognises something's there but I just can't see it. I also tried `kable(df, escape = F) %>% kable_styling(fixed_thead = T)` which renders the table but without colour

Comment: @stevec It sounds like you are trying to make a table in html? It may not be that obvious but the solution provided here is for latex. You could try to use cell_spec in kableextra, See [this for details](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#celltext_specification). I guess it's not the cleanest solution but at least it's better than writing raw html/latex.

Comment: @stevec The example there uses `dplyr` but to the end `cell_spec` just writes raw html or latex code depending on the kniting environment. Nothing fancy there

Answer (score 6):

Not a `knitr` solution...
You can modify specific cells with `DT::datatable` `formatStyle`. It has more display options and I'm using `list(dom = "t")` to turn them off and `ordering = FALSE` to remove sorting options from the top off the table.

```
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
df %>%
    datatable(options = list(dom = "t", ordering = FALSE), 
              rownames = FALSE,
              width = 10) %>%
    formatStyle("CPU", backgroundColor = styleEqual(93, "red"))
```

[image]

If you prefer `kable` way then you should try [`kableExtra`](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra). They have option to [change background for specified rows](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html).

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using my `huxtable` package:

```
library(huxtable)
ht <- as_hux(df)
ht <- set_background_color(ht, where(ht > 80), "red")
ht
```