# Table cell condition w/ Kable in R

Tags: r, datatable, kable, kableextra

I try to color the cells (data_a) if it matches to the data_b with kable, I saw the ifelse function in cell_spec but I didn't succeed.

```
data_a <- data.table("01:05", "01:05", "01:16", "00:33", "00:52")
data_b <- data.table("00:02", "01:05", "02:30")

kable(data_a, row.names = FALSE, format = "html") %>%
      kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "center")
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242281/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-cell-in-kable-output-table-in-knitr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
library(data.table)
data_a <- data.table(a =c("01:05", "01:05", "01:16", "00:33", "00:52"))
data_b <- data.table(b =c("00:02", "01:05", "02:30"))
library(kableExtra)

data_a %>%
  mutate(a = cell_spec(a, "html", color = ifelse(a %in% data_b$b, "green", "red"))) %>%
  kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
```

[image]