# How to color one cell with kableExtra

Tags: r, kableextra

I am just trying to highlight one cell in my table with kableExtra. The issue that I am having is that some of my cells have $s and ()s. Here is what it looks like

```
df3 <- data.frame(
  "Bitcoin Price:" = c("Snow Panther B1+", "ASICminer 8 nano", "S9", "Avalon 921", "Dragonmint T1", "Edit E11++"), 
  "3000" = c("($270.71)", "($3376.85)", "($115.80)", "($530.81)", "($1108.14)", "($1035.42)"),
  "6000" = c("$1050.37", "($1004.31)", "$666.06", "$547.62", "($245.39)", "$1337.12"), 
  "9000" = c("$2371.44", "$1368.24", "$1447.92", "$1626.04", "$617.35", "$3709.66"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
df3 %>%
  mutate(
    `6000`[,2] = cell_spec(`6000`[,2], color = "red", bold = T)
  ) %>%
  select("Bitcoin Price:", everything()) %>%
  kable(align = "c", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", "striped", full_width = F)  %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Current Difficulty" = 3)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("Statistics Calculated 2019"), notation = "symbol")
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I feel like I am close. I am trying to make the cells with the value ($1004.31), red.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you change the color of the cell in kable output table in knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46242281/9855745)

Comment: It not a duplicate. I can't use the `>80` that they use since I have special characters in the cell

Comment: It isn't the exact same as the flagged dupe because they aren't using the exact same statement being checked for true or false, but `x > 80` and `x == "($1004.31)"` aren't substantially different—the same methods of setting the color based on a logical statement apply. However, I think that isn't a great dupe since it only mentions `kableExtra` and relies on Latex, which may or may not be relevant for you. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54963523/5325862) seems more appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df3 %>%
  mutate(`6000` = cell_spec(`6000`, "html",color = ifelse(`6000` == "($1004.31)", "red", "grey"))) %>%
  select("Bitcoin Price:", everything()) %>%
  kable(align = "c", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", "striped", full_width = F)  %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Current Difficulty" = 3)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("Statistics Calculated 2019"), notation = "symbol")
```